# how to i implement Apple in-app Subscriptions in Flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-subscription

I want to provide auto or even Manuel renewable subscription in my Flutter App for iOS devices. Users can subscribe for 1 Month or 1 year.

Which one is the best? How to implement? Are these secure?

i tired [Square Plugin](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-flutter-plugin/blob/master/doc/enable-applepay.md); but got this response from Apple

> Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase
>
> We noticed that your app offers a subscription with a mechanism other
>   than the in-app purchase API.
>
> Specifically, subscription to view digital content within the app.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure that the
>   subscription for products used within the app is offered using the
>   in-app purchase API, with the exception of the content specified in
>   guideline 3.1.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

and

> In-App Purchase
>
> It may be appropriate to revise your app to use the in-app purchase
>   API to provide content purchasing functionality.
>
> In-app purchase provides several benefits, including:
>
> - The flexibility to support a variety of business models.
> - Impacting your app ranking by consolidating your sales to one app rather than distributing them across multiple apps.
> - An effective marketing vehicle to drive additional sales of new content.
>
> For information on in-app purchase, please refer to the following
>   documentation:
>
> In-App Purchase for Developers
>
> In-App Purchase Programming Guide
>
> For step-by-step instructions on in-app purchase creation within App
>   Store Connect, refer to App Store Connect Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Square to sell digital goods in your app. Apple will only allow you to use [StoreKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit).

You can implement this directly, which may be annoying for flutter especially for subscriptions. You can also use an SDK like [RevenueCat's Flutter SDK](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/flutter). (Full disclosure, I'm the CEO of RevenueCat).

Comment: that's great, any tutorials for this SDK ? -- Edit: nvm, i got it through the link you posted, i will try it now